# What is the grammar of the construction "Prove them wrong"? Why not "to prove they are wrong"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, parsing

"**Prove them wrong**." this sentence was a part of this phrase: "Everyone thinks I'm guilty. It's time to prove them wrong."
What does the hero literally means, saying "Prove them wrong."?

How to understand this words? Which variant describes the idea better:

> Everyone thinks I'm guilty. It's time to prove **they are/were wrong**.

*or*

> Everyone thinks I'm guilty. It's time to prove **them that they are/were wrong**.

*or*

> Everyone thinks I'm guilty. It's time to prove **them the opposite**?

What kind of grammar is it? I would say just "to prove they are wrong." The form of word they ("them") confused me.

Comment: *to prove them wrong = to prove [to them, everyone, myself, you,...] [that] **they are** wrong*.

Comment: whar kind of grammar is it? I would say just "to prove they are wrong." The form of word they("them") confused me.

Answer (score 1):

Of your options

> Everyone thinks I'm guilty. It's time to prove they are/were wrong.

That would be fine choosing *are* or *were* according to when they thought it.

> Everyone thinks I'm guilty. It's time to prove them that they are/were wrong.

That contains either an unnecessary *them* or has a missing *to* before the *them*.

?Everyone thinks I'm guilty. It's time to prove them the opposite?

The *them* is again unnecessary.

The basic construction in the original statement *prove them wrong* is verb noun/pronoun adjective. We have phrases like "paint it black", "Kiss it better", "Drive the teacher crazy" and so on.